# Remove extra indent after switch statement, when editing a .cpp file

Tags: vim

In my ~/.vimrc I have the following indentation settings:

```
" If available, load indenting file for specific file type.
filetype indent on    

" Does nothing more than copy the indnetation from the previous line,
" when starting a new line. autoindent does not interfere with other
" indentation settings
set autoindent

" Spaces are better than tab character
set smarttab expandtab    
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop = 4
```

This works fine in most cases. However there is one thing which is annoying me.

When I have a switch / case statement in a .cpp file, the case is automatically indented, e.g.

```
switch (x) {
    case A:
        // ...
```

While what I actually want is:

```
swith (x) {
case A:
    // ...
```

Is there any way to change this behaviour? (note: I don't have a specific .cpp syntax file in my `~/.vim/syntax` folder).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
 set cinoptions+=:0
```

That adds `:0` to the `cindent` settings, which says to indent case labels by zero characters.

To have that only apply to C and C++ files you can use:

```
au FileType c,cpp  setl cindent cinoptions+=:0
```

See [`:help cinoptions-values`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values) for other settings.

I use `cinoptions=:0,g0` so that `public:`, `protected:` and `private:` access specifiers are also not indented.

Comment: This doens't do exactly what I want, when typing `case` on the next line after a `switch (x) {` statement, `case` is aligned at column 0, while what I want is to align it a the column position of `switch (x)`  (as in my example).

Comment: Did you try it? Did you read the documentation I linked to? The `:N` options says: _"Place case labels N characters from the indent of the switch()."_ i.e. not in column 0, but 0 characters past the switch. Maybe you didn't turn on `cindent`?

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation and I understand your solution should be correct (according the doc.) I've tried with and without cindent turned on but it doesn't make a difference.  Probably I'm overlooking something and I'm spitting through my .vimrc, because with this solution, every time when I write `case:` it indents at column 0.

Comment: Ok I've just hit myself on the head. While I was quickly testing this solution, I consequently wrote `case:` instead of `case <someValue>:`. That's why it wasn't working.

Comment: Aha :-) Yeah, that gets treated as a jump label not a case label, and is controlled by `LN` rather than `:N`